# Need explanation on this line (trees, recursive)

Tags: c, recursion, tree

```
BOOL hasKey(pTreeNode tree, int key)
{
    BOOL ret = FALSE;
    if (tree != NULL)
    {
        if (key == tree->key)
            ret = TRUE;
        else
                         ret = (BOOL)(hasKey(tree->left, key) || hasKey(tree->right, key)); *//here*

    }
    return ret;
}
```

This is a function that checks if a given "key" is in the tree.
I can't understand what's the logic behind the line where I put a comment, also I would like to know if this code would do the same:

```
BOOL hasKey(pTreeNode tree, int key)
{
    BOOL ret = FALSE;
    if (tree != NULL)
    {
        if (key == tree->key)
            ret = TRUE;
        else { ret = hasKey(tree->left,key);
               if (ret == FALSE)
                 ret = hasKey(tree->right,key);
             }

    }
    return ret;
}
```

I don't have the full code, this is why I can't test if both do the same, it's a question from an exam.

I hope everything is clear! Thanks!

Comment: Yes, basically they are the same. There's probably some obscure corner of the language where they might differ, but otherwise the two should produce identical results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the second snippet is equivalent.
Another way to put it would be

```
BOOL hasKey(pTreeNode tree, int key)
{
    BOOL ret = FALSE;
    if (tree != NULL)
    {
        if (key == tree->key)
            ret = TRUE;
        else if (hasKey(tree->left,key)) 
            ret = TRUE;
        else if (hasKey(tree->right,key))
            ret = TRUE;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

The line

```
ret = (BOOL)(hasKey(tree->left, key) || hasKey(tree->right, key));
```

uses the [logical operator ||](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_logical), which is short-circuiting. This means:

> If the result of lhs compares unequal to zero, then rhs is not evaluated at all (so-called short-circuit evaluation)

Also not that the return type of this operator is `int`. That is probably the reason for explicitly casting the result to `BOOL`.

Comment: How are they both the same as   ret = (BOOL)(hasKey(tree->left, key) || hasKey(tree->right, key)); ? I don't understand what happens with this line, can you elaborate on it?

Comment: I added a bit of explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The logical OR `||` (as any other logical operator) is not necessarily used in an if-statement: it simply returns an integer value which is either 1 (true) or 0 (false).
In your case you simply store this result in a variable.